# Why do .htaccess redirects work on a url with www in it but not without?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two URLS which I need to work using my redirects:

example.com/john_doe and www.example.com/john_doe

These both need to become >>

www.example.com/?name=john_doe OR example.com/?name=john_doe

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/code(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://example.com/index.php?name=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have been banging my head against this for hours!

Comment: because www.example.com is different from example.com as far as .htacess rewrites are concered. you should redirect www. to non-www first and formost. (put that re write at the top of the rules file)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, either.

Comment: What happens if you use `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?name=$1 [R=301,L]`?

Comment: I never got an answer, but this is the end result that worked:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/code(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logos(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+)$ http://www.recognitiondoneright.com/index.php?name=$1_$2 [L,NC,QSA]`